# Falling Respawn

Tags: c#, windows, unity-game-engine, game-physics

Im making a platform game with Unity and Im programming with C#. I have a Ball Control script which handles the input and the physics behind its continuous bouncing. I also have a BounceTrigger script which make the ball stop and then make it bounce again. Im trying to implement a respawn with the player should be respawning at the last platform not destructible he has bounced over.

Ball Control Script 
    public float velocity = 2;

```
bool alreadyBounced;
bool boost;
float boostMultiplier;
Vector3 boostVelocityAdd;

int fallY = 10;
BounceTrigger platform;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
    alreadyBounced = false;

    float appliedVelocity = velocity * (boost ? boostMultiplier : 1);
    Vector3 direction = Vector3.zero;

    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A)) { direction = Vector3.left; rigidbody.AddForce(direction * appliedVelocity, ForceMode.VelocityChange);}
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D)) { direction = Vector3.right; rigidbody.AddForce(direction * appliedVelocity, ForceMode.VelocityChange);}
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W)) { direction = Vector3.forward; rigidbody.AddForce(direction * appliedVelocity, ForceMode.VelocityChange);}
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S)) { direction = -Vector3.forward; rigidbody.AddForce(direction * appliedVelocity, ForceMode.VelocityChange); }

    if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftArrow) || Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.A)) { direction = -Vector3.left; rigidbody.AddForce(direction * appliedVelocity, ForceMode.VelocityChange); }
    if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.RightArrow) || Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.D)){ direction = -Vector3.right; rigidbody.AddForce(direction * appliedVelocity, ForceMode.VelocityChange); }
    if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.UpArrow) || Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.W)) { direction = -Vector3.forward; rigidbody.AddForce(direction * appliedVelocity, ForceMode.VelocityChange); }
    if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.DownArrow) || Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.S)) { direction = Vector3.forward; rigidbody.AddForce(direction * appliedVelocity, ForceMode.VelocityChange); }
    CheckFalling ();
}

public void CheckFalling(){
    if(this.transform.position.y < fallY){
        Respawn();
    }
}

public void Respawn(){
    this.transform.position = lastPlatform.transform.position + Vector3.up;
}



public void Bounce(BounceTrigger platform, float upVelocity) {

    var reboteGO = (GameObject) GameObject.FindWithTag ("TextoRebote");
    var reboteComp = reboteGO.GetComponent<BounceCounter>();

    if(!alreadyBounced)
    {
        if(!platform.isDestructible){
            lastPlatform = platform;
        }

        Debug.Log("Bounce");
        alreadyBounced = true;
        reboteComp.AumentarRebote();
        float downVelocity = rigidbody.velocity.y;
        rigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.up * (-downVelocity + upVelocity), ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        ResetBoost();
    }
}

public void Boost(float multiplier){
    if(!boost){
        Debug.Log("Boost");
        StartCoroutine(BoostCoroutine(multiplier));
    }
}

public void ResetBoost(){
    if(boost){
        Debug.Log("Reset boost");
        boost = false;
        Vector3 velocityAdd = rigidbody.velocity;
        velocityAdd.x = velocityAdd.x / boostMultiplier * (boostMultiplier - 1);
        velocityAdd.z = velocityAdd.z / boostMultiplier * (boostMultiplier - 1);
        velocityAdd.y = 0;
        rigidbody.AddForce(-velocityAdd, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    }
}

public void RestarVida(){
    var vidaGO = (GameObject) GameObject.FindWithTag ("TextoVida");
    var vidaComp = vidaGO.GetComponent<LifeCounter>();
    vidaComp.RestarVida ();
}

IEnumerator BoostCoroutine(float multiplier){
    yield return 0;
    yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
    boost = true;
    boostMultiplier = multiplier;
    Vector3 velocityAdd = rigidbody.velocity;
    Debug.Log(velocityAdd);
    velocityAdd.x = velocityAdd.x * (boostMultiplier - 1);
    velocityAdd.z = velocityAdd.z * (boostMultiplier - 1);
    velocityAdd.y = 0;
    rigidbody.AddForce(velocityAdd, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    Debug.Log(velocityAdd);
}
```

Bounce Trigger script: 
`
public float upVelocity = 10;

```
public bool isDestructible = false;

public virtual void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider){
    collider.GetComponent<BallControl>().Bounce(this, upVelocity);
}
```

when I compile this I get a nullReferenceException 
`

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: When you ask for help because of an error, you should post the entire error, because some times the output shows line of code where the error happened.

Comment: IAssets/GameAssets/Scripts/BallControl.cs(56,33): error CS0103: The name `lastPlatform' does not exist in the current context || Sorry new to this :S

Comment: Where do you declare `lastPlatform`?

Comment: Ok, I think that I got it. Check answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have a global variable `BounceTrigger platform;` instead of `BounceTrigger lastPlatform;`, so `lastPlatform` don't exists anywhere in your code.

Comment: Oh thanks for fast answer. Now I got a NullReferenceException: "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
BallControl.Respawn () (at Assets/GameAssets/Scripts/BallControl.cs:44)
BallControl.CheckFalling () (at Assets/GameAssets/Scripts/BallControl.cs:39)
BallControl.Update () (at Assets/GameAssets/Scripts/BallControl.cs:34)"

Comment: try `this.Respawn()`. And the same to all functions. Call them using `this.`. Btw, I'm not a c# user so I don't know exactly what is happening.